# Checking parameter values for method at run time effectively through common code part in framework

Tags: java, frameworks

The parameter can be checked as follows for one case

```
public abstract class AbstractCHeck{
protected boolean afterObjectChecked( boolean originalResult)
    {
        return originalResult;
    }   

     protected void beforeObjectChecked(Object object)
    {
        Assert.notNull(object, getClass().getName() + " null values");

    }
    public  boolean doAllErroeFreeOperation(Object object)
    {   
        beforeObjectChecked(object); // THIS CODE PROTECT AGAINST NULL BEFORE ACTUAL METHOD IS CALLED.
        boolean result = doActualOperation(object);
        return afterObjectChecked(result);
    }
public abstract boolean doActualOperation(Object obj);

public  class mainCheck extends AbstractCHeck{

public  boolean doActualOperation(Object obj){

// some operation done


}
Client{
Maincheck clientprogram=new Maincheck();
clientprogram.doAllErroeFreeOperation(null); // 
}
```

**CaseII.**
Interceptor can be used before calling actual method and checking its value.

**What can be other cases that can catch the runtime exception effectively so that the client code does not have to deal for it and the solution can be provided from common code like framework code?**

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce new type classes which wrap values and guaranty certain constraints. Then use these as parameter types. Example(s):

```
public final class NotNull<T> {
  public final T value;

  public NotNull(T t) {
    if(t==null) throw new NullPointerException();
    value=t;
  }
}

public final class NotNegative {
  public final int value;

  public NotNegative(int i) {
    if(i<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    value=i;
  }
}

public class Example {
  public void doSomethig(NotNegative ni, NotNull<String> s) {
    String str=s.value; int i=ni.value; // not checks needed
  }
}
```

This may even save check overhead if values are used more than once.